# Reversing a uniq command on bash

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to find the number of times a particular email ID repeats. Piping `uniq -c` with the output I get `420 aol.com` but I need `aol.com 420` how to I do this because `uniq -c` applies as a prefix count

Comment: add a sample input with emails and expected output... your question as such doesn't have enough detail to suggest a solution.. see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sundeep the input is abc123@aol.com and current output : 1 aol.com ; meaning 1 aol.com email was found ; The output I need is : aol.com 1

Comment: oh ok, that is easy to do and you've got an answer already :) see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe the output to `awk`:

```
string='420 aol.com'
echo "$string" | awk '{print $2,$1}'

aol.com 420
```

By default, `awk` separates each field by spaces.

- `420` is the 1st field `$1`
- `aol.com` is the 2nd field `$2`.

This simply tells `awk` to print each of these field in reverse order. `{print $2,$1}`

Comment: Does this work even if it's a list
420 aol.com
123 yahoo.com
11 gmail.com
would this give 
aol.com 420
yahoo.com 123
gmail.com 11

Comment: sure it will. the output of `uniq` will display each result set in new line. `awk` would just swap `1st` and `2nd` columns of this output.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of email addresses such as:

```
$ cat emails.txt
1@aol.com
2@yahoo.com
3@aol.com
```

and you need the count of their domains, using awk:

```
$ awk -F@ '{a[$2]++} END {for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' emails.txt
aol.com 2
yahoo.com 1
```

The records are outputed in no particular order. If using Gnu awk, records can be ordered using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";` (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) of options) in the beginning of the `BEGIN` block.